# How to get the column title and first column row value for a cell in javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have JavaFX tableview that I have created dynamically. When one double-clicks on a cell on the tableview, I need to get the name of the column the cell is in and the value of the first cell in the row this cell is in. I have tried searching over google and found no particular solution to this problem. Kindly show me some sample code.

Comment: 1) learn how to use TableView 2) learn how to use TableView 3) learn how to use TableView ;) In particular, learn about how virtualized controls (like Table-/Tree-/ListView) are showing there data .. that is with XXCells .. at the end of the day, it's a custom TableCell that you need (which has all the knowledge that you are after). When stuck, come back with a [mcve] that demonstrates the concrete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first, let's assume your TableView is attached to a model:

```
public TableView<MyModel> myTable;
```

where MyModel is something like:

```
public class MyModel {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    // ... etc.
}
```

so, MyModel is a common POJO. You can have columns of your TableView like:

```
TableColumn<MyModel, Integer> id = new TableColumn<>("ID");
id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
TableColumn<MyModel, String> name = new TableColumn<>("Name");
name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
```

and then, to add the columns to your table:

```
myTable.getColumns().addAll(id, name);
```

Now, let's listen to the click event using a rowFactory:

```java
myTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<MyModel> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        // check for non-empty rows, double-click with the primary button of the mouse
        if (!row.isEmpty() && event.getClickCount() == 2 && event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            MyModel element = row.getItem();
            // now you can do whatever you want with the myModel variable.
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    });
    return row ;
});
```

That should do the work.

Comment: can I achieve the same if my tableview is not attached to a model?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are creating a tableView. Because you are going in a non traditional way of not using a model.

Comment: Your approach triggers the even on a click anywhere in the `TableView` (where it's not consumed) using any mouse button and does not take into account the click count. It would be better to add the handler to rows produced by a custom `rowFactory` and check for `mouseButton`, `clickCount` and whether the row is actually non-empty. Item and item index can be retrieved via row object in this case.

Comment: thanks for your comment @fabian , i've changed the answer taking into consideration using a rowFactory.